# Yii2, redirect doesn't work in a static function

Tags: function, redirect, static, yii2

It's a very strange behavior, it never happened to me.

I have the index action in my SiteController :

```
public function actionIndex(){
  Installer::ManageInstall(); //Here I have separated code
  $this->render('myView');. 
}
```

Then in the static function of the class Installer:

```
class Installer {
  public static function ManageInstall(){          
          return  Yii::$app->controller->redirect(['install']);

  }
}
```

The problem is that yii totally ignores the redirection,and I do not know why, never redirect.

I tried directly  and it work's :

```
public function actionIndex(){
   return  Yii::$app->controller->redirect(['install']);//Here works fine
        $this->render('myView');. 
     }
```

You may ask, because I make this silly example, but in reality I have simplified code to the minimum just to show the problem. Actually the Installer class, redirects using another condition, which I have not put because it has nothing to do with the problem.

I tried with this expressions:

```
     Yii::$app->response->redirect(['install'])->send(); return;
```

and

```
 Yii::$app->controller->redirect('install'); //without Return statement
```

..and nothing

Answer (score 0):

It should work this way:

```
return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['install'])->send();
```

Please, let me know of the result of this.

Comment: @TomasGrecioRamirez Are you doing an ajax request?

Comment: No, is a  regular Get Request.  
I have actually tracked the Yii Core code, and execute it but it does not redirect, on line 884 of the redirect () function of the yii \ web \ Response class, place a die() function ; and abort.

Comment: @TomasGrecioRamirez try adding `return` to `Installer::ManageInstall();` and let me know how that goes. It should look like `return Installer::ManageInstall();`.

Comment: Yes It works, but in this case, Never passes this code line, because return is there. The purpose the ManageInstall function is evaluate some conditions; according to this, passes or redirect

Comment: @TomasGrecioRamirez How are you expecting this to redirect while doing anything else? If you need it to do something else, the redirect should be the last line of code, that is executed.

Comment: @TomasGrecioRamirez If you give me the entire function, I can rewrite it for you to do what you want it to do.